# Not able to pass parameters through Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using remote PowerShell deployment via VSTS and calling the deployment script.

When I am running this script from a VSTS agent (agent is running on Windows 2008 R2) and deploying on a machine (target) with Windows 2012, the script is able to pass the parameters. But when I am trying to deploy it on a target machine with Windows 2008 none of the arguments are passed.

Edit, for better reference, pasting the complete code of the function:

```
function ExecuteDSCScript([string]$file, [string]$machine, [object]$params) {
    # Sample value for $file is MyDeploymentFolder\MyDeploymentScript.ps1
    $arguments = ""

    foreach ($param in $params) {
        $arguments = $arguments + " -" + $param.name + " '" + $param.value + "'" #Param is a key value pair
    }

    Write-Verbose $arguments.ToString() -Verbose

    $command = $file + $arguments + " -Ensure " + $Ensure + " -DeployServerName " + $machine #Forming PS command for remote execution

    # writing command in log with our password
    $paramslogging = $params

    foreach ($param in $paramslogging) {
        if ($param.Name.ToLower() -eq "password") {
            #masking the password so that it doesnt appear on console logs
            $param.Value= "************"
        }
    }
    $argumentslogging = ""

    foreach ($param in $paramslogging) {
        $argumentslogging = $argumentslogging + " -" + $param.Name + " '" + $param.Value + "'"
    }

    $commandlogging = $file + $argumentslogging + " -Ensure " + $Ensure + " -DeployServerName " + $machine

    Write-Verbose $commandlogging -Verbose  # I am able to get the complete list of parameters here (i.e. value of $argumentslogging)

    $result = Invoke-Expression -Command $command
}
```

All the arguments in the script `$file` is coming as empty due to which the remote execution fails, I have also put logging in the invoked script and all values were empty when the target machine is 2008 R2, but when I try to run the same script on a machine with Windows Server 2012, it worked.

Update:-
One more difference below are the .Net versions of the machines:-
Agent - .Net 4.6
Target1 - .Net 4.6 (Where the script works)
Target2 - .Net 4.5.2 (Where the script doesn't work)

Comment: You would be best to include the script you are using including where variables are set. Otherwise we are not able to know what $file, $machine, and $arguments equals, or why it may have the variable reset to $null.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply. so the $arguments contain a list of arguments and before this statement I am displaying the arguments on console, so my script is able to resolve all the arguments but not able to pass it through. Again, the same script works when I try on a target machine which is running on Windows Server 2012

Comment: you need to edit your question and provide the script as a script block please, trying to explain it in the comments section doesn't work very well.

Comment: I completely get your point, for better context, added the complete code of my method

Comment: What is the output of `$arguments.GetType().FullName` before you run `Invoke-Command`? What arguments does `$file` expect, and how are they handled?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, $arguments is an array, wait let me get the full method signature and additional code with proper comments, it will give you little more context

Comment: Your updated code uses `Invoke-Expression`, not `Invoke-Command`. The two cmdlets do different things.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry, my bad, the method which I pasted is the correct one, it is Invoke-Expression and Invoke-Command. Apologies for the typo

Comment: So what exactly is becoming "null"? What does `$command` look like? What is the value of `$result`? Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this is not throwing any error, if you look at my last comment on the code, the script which it is trying to invoke is not receiving the parameters passed.

Comment: @indranilpal in the Pre-requisites document, windows server 2008r2 is not supported. It doesn't have Powershell 3.0. Did you install 3.0 manually? By the way, copy the script to your build agent, does this method works on Windows server 2008r2 without using TFS?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT You are absolutely right, but last tome I checked, PowerShell 5.0 was installed there, else I believe many other commands which is used before even calling this method would have failed. However, let me double check on powershell version

Comment: You still haven't answered several questions. What does `$command` look like (i.e. what are you actually trying to run)? What is the value of `$result`? What arguments does `$file` expect, and how are they handled?

Comment: @Ansgar In the code comments I have mentioned about $file, it is straightforward, I am trying to form a command in string (like "something.ps1 -param1 val") and executing it. If you have any specific query after reading the code snippet and the code comments, please let me know. Thanks a lot for your prompt responses, really appreciate that.

Comment: I believe I asked some very specific questions. Until you decide to actually answer them you're on your own. Have fun.

Comment: @Ansgar as I have already mentioned in my comment and the code comments, $file is path of ps file I am trying to invoke "myfolder\file.ps1", $command is nothing but "myfolder\file.ps1 -param1 val1 -param2 val2" the $result captures whatever the file.ps1 returns (which in my case is nothing). Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: Is `myfolder\file.ps1` a relative or absolute path? In case of a relative path: does it exist under the current working directory? How did you verify? Is the script invoked at all? Or does it just not get the parameters? How did you verify that?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes it is absolute path and as I have mentioned in the question. The same script is getting executed when the target machine is Windows Server 2012, even now the script is getting executed but without any parameters. As mentioned in the code comment, I have printed all the parameters in the target script (file.ps1), when I execute it on Windows Server 2012, I am able to print all the params, when the target machine is 2008 R2, none of the params are displayed.

Comment: You're probably better off using `Invoke-Command` with an explicit `-ArgumentList`. Using string concatenation for arguments has a way of failing when you're not expecting it.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks a lot for your suggestion, let me try that and update you.

Comment: @indranilpal Did you try Jeroen's suggestion, does it work?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT Sorry for my delayed reply, I was out of station. Yes Jeroen's solution worked in my case. I have modified the code to use Invoke-Command and it worked.

Comment: @indranilpal Could you please post an answer as the solution for this case.